# Is there a way to run specflow tests parallelly in .Net?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, parallel-processing, nunit, specflow

I have written few specflow scenarios for my GUI Automation which are integrated with Selenium Webdriver. I am also using NUnit as my Testing framework.

Most of the tests are not dependent on each other. Is there a way i can parallelize these tests so that some of them can run parallelly?

Also would this parallelism be achieved when i run the same tests using Jenkins or would we be needing a new solution for it to run parallelly on the CI server?

Answer (score 1):

From v2 specflow [supports the parallel features](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Parallel-Execution) of NUnit3.

If you are running your NUnit tests using the v3 console runner then I think that you can run them in parallel on the CI server already.